# Moxios Stubrequest with Regular Expression

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils, moxios

I have tried to use a moxios Stubrequest with a regex like `comments/.*/vote` but it is not working. The .* is populated with identifiers (integer). Any idea how to make this work? Thanks

Code

```
moxios.stubRequest('/comments/.*/vote', {
        status: 200,
        response: {
            success: true
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use a regular expression rather than a string. So your code would become:

```
moxios.stubRequest(/\/comments\/.*\/vote/, {
  status: 200,
  response: {
      success: true
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As an additional solution, you can wrap your `var` in a regular expression

```
var str = '/comments/.*/vote';
moxios.stubRequest(new RegExp(str), {
    status: 200,
    response: {
        success: true
    }
})
```